# Autolayout with UISegmented Control displaying strange layout and interaction behavior

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol, autolayout

I assume this may be a Xcode issue (meaning my issue), although I suppose it could stretch beyond.  I have an app that uses a UISegmentedControl to flip between categories.  During the layout process however, I am unable to position the control where I would like.  If I move it to where I would like and pin the positioning, the control moves in the opposite direction in both the simulator and my phone.  If I pin the control to the scrollview above it, then space it to where I like, the control no longer responds to taps.  I have included a screen shot to hopefully illustrate the issue I'm having.  I will admit that I have not had the opportunity to use the Autolayout feature very much, so it is new to me.  I do believe however I understand the principles.

I apologize I'm not able to post images yet... here is an image that tries and illustrates the issues I'm having.
http://www.uglyyellowbunny.com/images/stackoverflow/screenshots.png

The view looks correct however the buttons will not respond to any user interaction at all.   It feels like the "hit box", to use a game term, is no longer in the proper location.  The display behavior is standard across all iPhones, however only the 4 and 4s exhibits the interaction issue where the control refuses to respond to touches.

Have any of you seen issues like this before?  I apologize if I haven't explained myself very well and would be happy to answer any questions.  It seems like a cruel joke, move the control down and the further up the display it goes... try to lock it in position and whup... it will no longer work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question, and at the same time provide a way to remind myself how to fix this problem when I forget, here is the simple answer.

When designing the layout for iPhone, always use the iPhone 5 screen size.  When using the view size for an iPhone 5 - all the elements resize and format properly, and remain interactive.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess I would say another UI element is covering the segmented control, which would cause it not to respond to touches. Maybe the scrollview is expanding to cover the control.  Try changing the order of the elements so the segmented control is the top level element.

Comment: That was also my first thought. It is the top most element and when it slides on top of the scrollview it still responds.  Last night I only spaced it 20 pixels from the scrollview... and curiously enough the segmented control responded to taps if you aimed immediately above it.